# abi.encodePacked Is it necessary

Tags: solidity

```
function encodePackedTest(address a, uint b, string c) public pure returns(bytes32, bytes32){
    return (keccak256(a, b, c), keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c)));
}
```

From the results of the function, the returned value is the same, is it necessary for **abi.encodePacked** to use it?

Answer (score 5):

The 'old' version of `keccak256()` that accepts multiple parameters is deprecated. Internally it is doing something similar to `abi.encodePacked()` but it is not well defined for structs.

For simplicity it was decided that `keccak256()` only accept a single `bytes` parameter and the functionality of creating that array is moved to a separate function `abi.encodePacked()`.